# How to generate multiple test method from JSON?

Tags: java, testing, junit

I have a huge JSON-File which contains testcases. (No I don't wanna show it here because it doesn't matter in this case to know the file)
I parse the json file to my junit test - that works fine.
But I've got 50 testcases and if I want to show each in Junit like:  "test 0 from 50 passed"
and have a list like: test 1 passed, test 2 passed, test 3 failed..

I have to put each testcase into a method. How can I dynamically do this? Is this possible in Junit? Because when I'm parsing the json, I don't know how many cases I have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JUnit has direct support for CSV files, which means you can import and use them easily using `@CSVFileSource`.

However, since your case does not involve CSV files, I tried to create parametrized tests in JUnit 5 using JSON files.

Our class under test.

```java
public class MathClass {
    public static int add(int a, int b) {
        return a + b;
    }
}
```

Here's the JSON file I am using.

```
[
  {
    "name": "add positive numbers",
    "cases": [[1, 1, 2],[2, 2, 4]]
  },
  {
    "name": "add negative numbers",
    "cases": [[-1, -1, -2 ], [-10, -10, -20 ]]
  }
]
```

So, in JUnit 5 there is an annotation called `@MethodSource` which gives you the opportunity to provide arguments to your parametrized test. You only need to provide the method name. Here's my argument provider method.

```java
    @SneakyThrows
    private static Stream<TestCase> getAddCases() {
        final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        TypeReference<List<Case>> typeRef = new TypeReference<>() {};
        final File file = new File("src/test/resources/add-cases.json");
        final List<Case> cases = mapper.readValue(file, typeRef);
        return cases.stream()
                .flatMap(caze -> caze.getCases()
                                        .stream()
                                        .map(el -> new TestCase(caze.getName(), el)));
    }
```

In the code above, the class `Case` is used to map from the json object to Java Object and since the "cases" field is a multidimensional array, to represent each test case there is a class called `TestCase`. (Overall, this is not important for you, since you already are able to parse it, but I wanted to put it here anyway).

Finally, the test method itself.

```java
    @ParameterizedTest(name = "{index} : {arguments}")
    @MethodSource("getAddCases")
    void add_test(TestCase testCase) {
        final List<Integer> values = testCase.getValues();
        int i1 = values.get(0);
        int i2 = values.get(1);
        int e = values.get(2);
        assertEquals(e, MathClass.add(i1, i2));
    }
```

`@ParametrizedTest` annotation takes a `name` argument where you can provide a template for the test names. I just played around with the `toString` method of `TestCase` class to achieve a better description for each test case.

```java
@Override
public String toString() {
    return String.format("%s : (%s, %s) ==> %s", name, values.get(0), values.get(1), values.get(2));
}
```

And voila!

[image: Test cases]